# import order for sys.path for regular and namespace packages

Tags: python, import

As official doc says ([The Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path.

It will search package from first one to last one in `sys.path`.

But I encounter that a example doesn't meet this.

here is a example:

When I have installed flask:

```py
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__path__
['/home/yixuan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask']
```

and If I make a dir `flask` under my custom directory (which is /home/yixuan/temp), then I run this:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/yixuan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/home/yixuan/temp')
>>> sys.path
['/home/yixuan/temp', '', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/yixuan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__path__
['/home/yixuan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask']
```

(These are two separate interpreter sessions !)

And I do not know why flask package isn't my custom flask dir. In `sys.path`, the `/home/yixuan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` is placed in after `/home/yixuan/temp`, according to my understanding, it's not normal, isn't it ? if so, what cause could make this happen ?

Comment: Did you run both code blocks in the same session? Did you only create a *directory* ``flask``, or did you put any content such as a ``__init__.py`` file inside?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No, I am aware of the existing of the `sys.modules`

Comment: @Petronella It's just a empty directory, and it behaves same in python package.

Comment: An empty directory does not exactly behave like a Python package.

Comment: If your ``flask`` directory is just empty, it is not recognized as a regular package (it might be treated as an empty namespace package). Please try with a directory *containing a ``__init__.py`` or directly with a ``flask.py`` file.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I tried in several conditions, if and only if there is a `__init__.py` in my custom package with the same name, it works. And I also tried, if there are no same name pacakge exists in lib directory, my namespace package can be imported successfully. I wanna know what is the principle behind, I haven't found any description in official doc yet.

Comment: @yixuan The TLDR is that regular packages win against namespace packages. Note that namespace packages are useful but not commonly used, so both the documentation and third-party descriptions are somewhere between short, incomplete and outright wrong. If you really want to know about them, please *explicitly* mention that in your question to make it clear this is not just a mistake of accidentally using a namespace instead of regular package. A proper answer will require some digging, so it is helpful if the question is in shape to serve as a signpost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directory without an `__init__.py` (`flask/`) file is a namespace package, not a regular package (`flask/__init__.py`) or module (`flask.py`). While namespace packages are *recorded* in the order of `sys.path`, they are only used if neither a regular package or module is found at all.

---

> ## [PEP 420 -- Implicit Namespace Packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/)
>
> ...
>
> ### [Specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification)
>
> ...
>
> While looking for a module or package named "foo", for each directory in the parent path:
>
> - If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is imported and returned.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform and whether the `-> O` flag is specified. The list here is representative.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.
>
> If the scan completes without returning a module or package, and at least one directory was recorded, then a namespace package is created.
>
> ...

Answer (score -2):

See the [sys.path documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) regarding imports. Flask is now part of python 3 installations.

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches
> for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
> for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
> variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations.

Comment: I have read that. First, `flask` is not built-in module, and the directory (which `flask` package settles in) is in after the directory (which is my custom `flask` directory settles in), If search path in order in `sys.path`, it will import my custom `flask` then, right?